# CAKeyframeAnimation dropped frames for large animations

Tags: ios, performance, animation

I have a large animation(~30ish layers and ~150 keyframes). When I feed that information into a set of CAKeyframeAnimation object, the animation takes a while to start(understandable if it's big) but when it does start the frames that were supposed to happen during the loading period have been dropped and it picks up from there.

I'd really like to avoid this, I don't mind if the animation is delayed but I do mind if it drops a lot of frames.

Is there any way to mitigate this? Or should I just scrap the whole thing and implement my own animator in openGL ES?